# Determining Protocol in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

In Loadrunner, we have feature called "Protocol Advisor" which helps to determine the protocols for recording. Could you please suggest how to determine the protocol while recording a script in Jmeter?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter can record only [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/kab/docs/Web/HTTP) or [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocols therefore it cannot "advise" you anything. If your application uses HTTP/HTTPS protocols - JMeter will capture the requests using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-superpower-http-proxy-server)

With regards to other protocols which JMeter supports like:

- [FTP](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#FTP_Request)
- [JDBC](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)
- [LDAP](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#LDAP_Request)
- [SMTP](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler)
- [POP/IMAP](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler)
- etc.

although you can simulate requests using JMeter - you will not be able to record them.

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter is not having any protocol advisor as provided by Load Runner. If you have LR then use the protocol advisor and select the same protocol in jmeter, only if that works in LR.